# jquery - group or concatenate jquery objects created by a loop, so to use appendTo only once

Tags: jquery, for-loop, concatenation

I have a `for` loop to generate a row of `div`s, my code is

```
for(j=0; j<7; j++) {
   $('<div/>', {
     id: 'unique',
     html: 'whatever'
}).appendTo('#container');
```

This code seems to seek out #container for every iteration and appends a new div to it.

How do write the code so that I can go create all the divs first and then append to the container all at once?  Sorry, I tried searching for keywords such as concatenate/group/add jquery objects, and don't seem to have the right search results.

TIA

Comment: Why do you want to have the code only call `appendTo` once?

Comment: @JaredPar, because as I understand it, jquery only has to seek out the correct div once instead of many times as the iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xander's solution should work just fine.  I personally don't like working with 'long' HTML strings in js.  Here is a solution that looks more similar to your code.

```
var elements = [];
for(j=0; j<7; j++) {
    var currentElement = $('<div>', { id: i, text: 'div' });
    elements.push(currentElement[0]);
}
$('#container').append(elements);
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, this is kinda what I had in mind.  I do wonder if there is another way of 'grouping' objects, since this method introduces an array that could tax resources.

Comment: Yes, you could potentially pay a slight tax on the creation of jQuery objects.  However, you get added benefits of more easily binding events (you'd probably want to delegate the events if they're the same for every element), plus this way gives you the added benefit of creating a closure on those events(not demonstrated here), if needed. I don't think you will see any performance gains until you reach thousands of elements.

Comment: Hi Justin, the code works, but I don't understand the line elements.push(currentElement[0]);  Why does currentElement has the [0]?

Comment: It is because a jQuery object is created and you don't want to add the whole object just the first element in it.  A jQuery object is similar to an array.

Comment: Thanks Justin, can you point me to where I can learn more about what elements are part of the object?

Comment: No problem, you can learn more about jQuery objects here http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Object

Answer (score 4):

This could help

```
var htm = '';
for(j=0; j<7; j++) {
     htm+= '<div id="unique_'+i+'">whatever</div>';
}

$('#container').html(htm); // Or append instead of html
```

Comment: Thanks Jose/Xander, I did not really want to do it that way because I didn't want to mess with writing the text string.  I think Justin's code is more of what I had in mind.

Comment: OTOH, the creation of the string variable should be less taxing than jquery objects.